# Postman capturing elements where another element criteria is matched

Tags: javascript, json, postman

My response code is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 364,
        "siteName": "FX21 - PortA",
    },
    {
        "id": 364,
        "siteName": "FX21 - PortB",
    },
    {
        "id": 370,
        "siteName": "FX05 - ER",
    },
```

In postman I am wanting to populate an array variable with all siteName values only where id = 364. So my expected array is to look like `[FX21 - PortA, FX21 - PortB]`

I've tried the following but this only returns the first siteName value:

```
var requiredId = pm.response.json().find(function(element){
    if (element.id == "364"){

        return element;
    }
});
```

Comment: [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first match. You wanted to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

Comment: Sorry. That's a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Also instead of `if (element.id == "364"){` you should do `if (element.id ===364){`

Answer (score 0):

- Use a combination of `Array.filter` to filter `id` having value `364`.
- And `Array.map` to map it to an array of only `siteName` values.
- Along with destructuring assignment to extract the keys of the object:

```js
const response = [
    {
        "id": 364,
        "siteName": "FX21 - PortA",
    },
    {
        "id": 364,
        "siteName": "FX21 - PortB",
    },
    {
        "id": 370,
        "siteName": "FX05 - ER",
    }
]
function getSiteNameById(idFilter){
 return response.filter(({id}) => id === idFilter).map(({siteName}) => siteName);
}
console.log(getSiteNameById(364));
```

Or `Array.reduce` to do it in one shot where you can check for the id and then accumulate the element in the final array:

```js
const response = [
        {
            "id": 364,
            "siteName": "FX21 - PortA",
        },
        {
            "id": 364,
            "siteName": "FX21 - PortB",
        },
        {
            "id": 370,
            "siteName": "FX05 - ER",
        }
    ]
function getSiteNameById(idFilter){
 return response.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    return  ele.id === idFilter ? acc.concat(ele.siteName) : acc;
 }, []);
}
console.log(getSiteNameById(364));
```

Comment: `reduce` is a better choice where you have to filter and map both.

Comment: @31piy Yes I agree that is a better and concise approach! Thank you!